# Put optional input files for rule all in Snakemake

Tags: python, workflow, pipeline, snakemake

In my Snakemake project, I have a config.yaml file which allows users to run certain steps of the pipeline or not, for example:

```
DEG : 
   exec : True
```

And so, in the Snakefile, I include the rules associate with the DEG:

```
if config["DEG"]["exec"]:
   include: "rules/classic_mapping.smk"
   include: "rules/counts.smk"
   include: "rules/run_DESeq2.smk"
```

The problem is, now I would like to dynamically specify the output files in the "all" rule, so that Snakemake knows which files to generate based on the parameters entered by the user. For example I had in mind to proceed as follows:

```
rule all:   
   input:
       if config["DEG"]["exec"]:
          "DEG/DEG.txt"
       if config["DTU"]["exec"]:
          "DTU/DTU.txt"
```

but it doesn't work:
    SyntaxError in line 58 of Unexpected keyword if in rule definition (Snakefile, line 58)

I would need an outside point of view to find an alternative because Snakemake should not work on this way

Thank's by advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use snakemake's ability to take functions as input and put the if loop in a function. A sample implementation could be as follows

```py
def get_input(wildcards):
    input_list = []
    if config["DEG"]["exec"]:
          input_list.append("DEG/DEG.txt")
    if config["DTU"]["exec"]:
          input_list.append("DTU/DTU.txt")
    return input_list

rule all:
    input:
        get_input
```

You can customize the `get_input` function to include additional conditions if required. This is documented further [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#functions-as-input-files).

Another alternate way of doing this which is **far less readable and not recommended** but can work incase an addtional function is to be avoided is as follows

```py
rule all:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: "DEG/DEG.txt" if config["DEG"]["exec"] else [],
        lambda wildcards: "DTU/DTU.txt" if config["DTU"]["exec"] else [],
```

Comment: This solution should work, but since the input does not depend on wildcards, it is not necessary to use input functions.

Comment: Now that I see it, I agree your solution does make more sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Inputs are just lists of files. You can define them outside the rule definition:

```python
deg_files = []
if config["DEG"]["exec"]:
    deg_files.append("DEG/DEG.txt")

dtu_files = []
if config["DTU"]["exec"]:
    dtu_files.append("DTU/DTU.txt")

rule all:
    input:
        deg_files,
        dtu_files,
```